# Does here have custom map style?

Tags: here-api

Does here api support custom map style like what MapBox does?

This link is for Mapbox:
https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/styles/#Create.a.style

I just found a little information on here website at: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/example-custom-map-style.html

Comment: Map Tile API also supports different styles which are documented in link below, however providing own colors is currently not supported. https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/resource-base-maptile.html

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: is there any update on this? it still seems impossible?

Comment: 3 years later and this feature is still not possible...?

Answer (score 0):

From our earlier reply
"Map Tile API also supports different styles which are documented in link below, however providing own colors is currently not supported"
We encourage you to loot at https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/resource-base-maptile.html

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility to visualize and create a custom map style for HERE Maps API for JavaScript 3.1.x, in the following tool:

**[Map Style Editor](https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/)**

[image]

This is a rather low-level tool, as you are editing the *yaml* style file directly. To know what to edit, the Inspection tool (the "eye" icon above the zoom selector on the map) is handy, as it shows the properties names of the inspected feature.

See also the [Custom Styles](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.3/dev_guide/topics/custom-styles.html) section in the documentation of HERE Maps API for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this https://developer.here.com/documentation/style-editor/user_guide/index.html.

If you have an account on platform.here.com, you can access the editor using this URL: https://platform.here.com/style-editor