# Can I change Traffic information display on the Map?

Tags: here-api

As what Here doc says, Traffic flow lines are color coded as follows:

Green - Normal

Amber - High

Red - Very High

Black - Blocking

I have two questions as below:

- Can I change Traffic information display on the Map based on what developers define? like changing color from 'Amber - High' to 'pink - High'.
- Can I change the color of my route?

Here's doc is here:
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/traffic.html

Thanks,

Comment: I knew how to change the color of my route, but I still don't know how to change Traffic information display on the Map based on what developers define. like changing 'Amber - High' to 'pink - High'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, traffic colors are not changeable right now.

For the route color, use setColor of MapRoute:
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-maproute.html

Comment: Hi Marco, could you please also answer this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664468/does-here-have-custom-map-style